# Problems with MVC 4 Azure Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have deployed an MVC 4 website on Azure over the last half an hour or so and I am having a few problems with the website.

1. One page is meant to be pulling information out of the database and displaying it. The content is in Sql Azure, but nothing is still coming out.
2. The user logins, and can go into a dashboard to add content to the system.

This are the two problems I am finding but a 404 error displays.

Comment: did you try call the full url: http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/home/index?

Comment: and it returns 404 too?

Answer (score 0):

MVC routing issue?

Check you don't have something strange in Global.asax.cs

Are you using Forms based authentication?

Are you using additional libraries / components like ELMAH that could be causing the issue?

Have you configured a custom domain i.e. mydomain.com?

Also refer to section 'View failed request tracing logs' in the [Troubleshooting Windows Azure Web Sites in Visual Studio](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/)

Comment: Nope no MVC routing issue to be honest.No I have not implmented ELMAH.  Thanks might look into it.